# How can I add a font in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to use a specific font with Crystal Reports XI.  Specifically, I want to use Helvetica-Bold-TT.  I see this shows up in Microsoft Word, but not in Crystal.  Is it possible to add this font to the font list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when I installed a font in my pc (drag and drop inside `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder) i found it also in Crystal Reports IDE.

But when you deploy the report, you have to install the font on the server, too.

Comment: I realized that just because the Font is present in Office does not mean it is installed in the Fonts on the system.  This is correct.